# Unlist nested list by name

Tags: r, list, nested

I import a nested list of unknown length (here 2) and unknown names (here iter1 and iter2) and get the names of the list:

```
iter1 <- list(1, 2, 3, 4)
iter2 <- list(1, 2, 3, 4)

nested_list <- list(iter1 = iter1, iter2 = iter2)

names <- names(nested_list)
```

The next thing I want to do is actually this:

```
unlist <- data.frame(x=unlist(nested_list$iter1))
```

But due to the fact I don't know the names beforehand I want to do something like this:

```
unlist <- data.frame(x=unlist(nested_list$names[1]))
```

Which is certainly not working. There is no error, but the created list is empty.

In the end I want to do something like this:

```
for(i in 1:length(nested_list)) {
   unlist <- data.frame(x=unlist(nested_list$names[i]))
   print(unlist)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Map`, avoiding the `names` vector.

```
data.frame(Map(unlist, nested_list)[1])
#   iter1
# 1     1
# 2     2
# 3     3
# 4     4
```

Or, in order to give column names with `mapply`:

```
data.frame(x=mapply(unlist, nested_list)[,1])
#   x
# 1 1
# 2 2
# 3 3
# 4 4
```

The `1` in brackets indicates first list name, use `2` for the second name accordingly.

---

*Data*

```
nested_list <- list(iter1 = list(1, 2, 3, 4), iter2 = list(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
unlist <- data.frame(x=unlist(nested_list[names[1]]))
```

such that

```
       x
iter11 1
iter12 2
iter13 3
iter14 4
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I get what you intended as result, could you precise it if needed ?

```r
iter1 <- list(1, 2, 3, 4)
iter2 <- list(1, 2, 3, 4)

nested_list <- list(iter1 = iter1, iter2 = iter2)
names <- names(nested_list)

cbind.data.frame(lapply(nested_list, unlist))
#>   iter1 iter2
#> 1     1     1
#> 2     2     2
#> 3     3     3
#> 4     4     4
```